# Need to restrict mongodb from particular Ip

Tags: database, mongodb, security

I have one instance on which my code is running and other instance MongoDB is running, I need to restrict the MongoDB from my instance only, It only works when I set the bind it to 0.0.0.0 else I am giving the IP of my instance it's not working. Please help. I am using mongo 4.0

Comment: Hi Rohit, you want to access it from your machine only and restrict all other or vice versa?

Comment: Hi< I want to access MongoDB from my local pc and the instance on which my node app is running